# XSL predicates in location path?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this list of users and want to filter it so it only shows users that are same age and have the same last name - desired out put is

25, Smith, Harry

25, Smith, Charlie

36, Jones, Thomas

36, Jones, Henry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="duplo.xsl"?>
<report>
    <user>
        <age>25</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
            <firstName>Harry</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
        <user>
        <age>25</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
            <firstName>Charlie</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <age>36</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Jones</lastName>
            <firstName>Thomas</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <age>36</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
            <firstName>Henry</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <age>36</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Jones</lastName>
            <firstName>Henry</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <age>47</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Jones</lastName>
            <firstName>Paul</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <age>47</age>
        <name>
            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
            <firstName>Simon</firstName>
        </name>
    </user>
</report>
```

So far I have come to this stylesheet, that gives me a list of the second person in each "pair".

25, Smith, Charlie

36, Jones, Henry

My guess is that I should write something more clever than [2] in for-each, but so far I haven't found out what to use instead. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:key name="duplo" match="user" use="concat(age, '+', name/lastName)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <duplo>

        <xsl:for-each select="//user[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('duplo', concat(age, '+', name/lastName))[2])]">

            <xsl:sort select="age"/> 
            <xsl:sort select="name/lastName"/> 
            <xsl:sort select="name/firstName"/> 

                <user>
                    <age><xsl:value-of select="age"/></age>
                    <name>
                        <lastName><xsl:value-of select="name/lastName"/></lastName>
                        <firstName><xsl:value-of select="name/firstName"/></firstName>
                    </name>
                </user>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </duplo>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an inner `xsl:for-each` to get all of items in the group, rather than just picking the "second" one....

```
<xsl:for-each select="//user[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('duplo', concat(age, '+', name/lastName))[2])]">
    <xsl:sort select="age"/> 
    <xsl:sort select="name/lastName"/> 
    <xsl:sort select="name/firstName"/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="key('duplo', concat(age, '+', name/lastName))">
        <user>
            <age><xsl:value-of select="age"/></age>
            <name>
                <lastName><xsl:value-of select="name/lastName"/></lastName>
                <firstName><xsl:value-of select="name/firstName"/></firstName>
            </name>
        </user>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```